# Duplicity + CloudFiles

Tags: linux, cloudfiles, duplicity

When attempting to backup to CloudFiles with Duplicity, I receive the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1494, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1488, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1322, in main
    action = commandline.ProcessCommandLine(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/commandline.py", line 1036, in ProcessCommandLine
    backup, local_pathname = set_backend(args[0], args[1])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/commandline.py", line 929, in set_backend
    globals.backend = backend.get_backend(bend)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 163, in get_backend
    return _backends[pu.scheme](pu)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backends/_cf_pyrax.py", line 67, in __init__
    % (e.__class__.__name__, util.uexc(e)),
NameError: global name 'util' is not defined
```

I am using Linux Mint 17 and followed this guide: http://gsusmonzon.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/backup-with-duplicity-and-rackspace.html

Answer (score 0):

Replaced error in file /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backends/_cf_pyrax.py on line 67

```
% (e.__class__.__name__, util.uexc(e)),
```

With:

```
% (e.__class__.__name__, duplicity.util.uexc(e))
```

pip install pyrax wasn't installing the latest version, so instead I ran the command:

```
pip install --upgrade git+git://github.com/rackspace/pyrax.git
```

Everything works now.